# How to use the following code to overlay the current canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this piece of code on this site and want to use it in my project. However I'm not sure how to change this so it doesn't push the contents off the page when opening the menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){

     if( $(this).text()=="Open")
     {
         $(this).text("Hide");
     }
     else
     {
        $(this).text("Open");
      }
    $("#panel").slideToggle("fast");
      });
    });
    </script>

    <style> 
    #panel,#flip
    {
        padding:5px;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#e5eecc;
        border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    #panel
    {
       padding:50px;
        display:none;
        width:90px;
        height: 200px
     }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button id="flip">Open</button>

    <div id="panel">Menu!</div>
    </div>
    <p>
    Something else on the page

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I think you are searching for the css style **"position:absolute"**
Please see it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you!

Comment: position:absolute does the trick, however the panel now covers the button, I can open it, but can never close it.

Comment: I've figured it out.. Thanks for your help!